# OOP like relationship in databases and Sync

Tags: database, oop

This question is about databases and relationships

I want to make a database of my electronics gear in my lab( resistrors, capacitors,diodes, tools etc ).

All of them have some common attributes that are in the table "Components" and some unique in a different table.

How am I supposed to connect each unique table with the common table so that it makes sense.

I am not familiar with databases but I am thinking like Object Oriented approach. The table "Components" should be a class like table and the other tables (Resistor, Capacitor etc) should inherit it and add some more...

[image: Database relationship]

Answer (score 0):

1 table in database is 1 class in application. inherit in class is relationship in table.I think in your case Resistor with component is n->1 and also for capacitor

Comment: I tried that :( but the data were not synced. The component table should be updated each time I add a resistor or a capacitor in the other tables. And it should be a unique entry in "Components" for each unique entry in the other tables( "Resistor", "Capacitor", etc )